# Equivalent of LEAP options further into future

Tags: options

If I wanted to buy LEAP options for a particular NYSE stock, however they only issue contracts that expire a maximum of 2 years in the future, are there are other alternative securities/contracts that would be equivalent to an option but would allow exposure to that particular asset for 3 years or potentially longer?

Answer (score 1):

You might find warrants or convertible bonds issued by the firm, though those may not be traded on an exchange (*i.e.* OTC only). What is more likely to be what you want would be buying a [FLEX option, which allows up to 15 years to expiry](http://www.cboe.com/products/flex#flexterms).

Comment: Would those be available to retail investors? I couldn't really find anything

Comment: Yes, but your broker will also have to allow access to them. Not all brokers even allow options trading.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a semi-equivalent solution in case this helps anyone else.

If one buys/shorts the stock using a margin loan, while buying option calls/puts to protect against a rise/drop in stock price it appears provide a similar solution, allowing one to hold the position for longer amounts of time, while adding leverage and limiting exposure.